# Android Studio Error while trying to add a Fragment to project

Tags: android, android-studio

Details of the error :

```
Android Studio 2.1.1

5:09:32 PM InvalidReferenceException: Error executing FreeMarker template: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> srcDir  [in template "root://other/BlankFragment/globals.xml.ftl" at line 7, column 34]

Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally null/missing, either specify a default value with myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use when-presentwhen-missing. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthessis: (myOptionVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionVar.foo)??

The failing instruction:
==> ${srcDir}  [in template "root://other/BlankFragment/globals.xml.ftl" at line 7, column 32] (show balloon)
***When Show balloon is clicked***
InvalidReferenceException
Error executing FreeMarker template: The following has evaluated to null or missing: ==> srcDir [in template "root://other/BlankFragment/globals.xml.ftl" at line 7, column 34] Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally null/missing, either specify a default value with myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use #if myOptionalVar??>when-present#else>when-missing#if>. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthessis: (myOptionVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionVar.foo)?? The failing instruction: ==> ${srcDir} [in template "root://other/BlankFragment/globals.xml.ftl" at line 7, column 32]
```

Comment: You need to provide more info on the error is caused. Take a look at this answer - Similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805983/freemarker-template-error-the-following-has-evaluated-to-null-or-missing-but

Comment: Thanks, after a couple of "invalidate caches / restart" routine - this error just disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

If you're facing this issue in a Udacity project, this is a know bug:

https://github.com/udacity/ud851-Exercises/issues/67

Similar issue also reported
[here](https://github.com/udacity/ud851-Sunshine/issues/24) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=232076).

Proposed workaround is:

Remove the following configuration from your project build.gradle and then clicking on sync now

```
String osName = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase(); 
if (osName.contains("windows")) { 
    buildDir = "C:/tmp/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}" 
}
```

Then close the project > Import the project again.

Comment: I am getting this error now: Error:Failed to crunch file H:\Dropbox\workspace_AndroidStudio\_Udacity_2_ToyApp\Lesson06-Visualizer-Preferences\T06.01-Exercise-SetupTheActivity\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\25.1.0\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png into H:\Dropbox\workspace_AndroidStudio\_Udacity_2_ToyApp\Lesson06-Visualizer-Preferences\T06.01-Exercise-SetupTheActivity\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png